# How can I bring back the "bounce" when scrolling in OS X?

Tags: snow-leopard, macos

I just system restored after a kernel panic, and I am no longer seeing this feature.  It used to be that when you scrolled (say, down this page in Firefox), there was some physics in the scroll, rather than a hard stop and start.  Since system restoring, this is gone.  How do I bring it back? I am using Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be referring to the "Scroll with inertia" option, which is found in System Preferences > Trackpad. If it's set to scroll with inertia, but inertial scrolling isn't working, try toggling it to "without inertia" then back to "with inertia".

If that doesn't work, you can try deleting the preference file, "com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist" found in ~/Library/Preferences. Then log out, log back in and check the Trackpad preferences again.

Answer (score 1):

Look at preferences for "Smooth scrolling"

Comment: preferences for what?

Comment: @water Open System Preferences. Click on General. Enable "Use smooth scrolling."

Comment: I don't see "General" under system preferences.  I'm on snow leopard

Comment: Snow Leopard doesn't support the "bounce".  Were you using some other 3rd party plug-in?

Comment: ...nope.  It was always there.  There's no way snow leopard doesn't support smooth scrolling, since I distinctly remember saying "The only UI upgrade with any value in this upgrade is the scrolling"

Comment: In the case of Snow Leopard, it would be under "Appearance" under the Personal listing. And kukoo is right, Snow Leopard does not support the "scrolling with inertia." That feature was introduced in Lion. In the future, please be as specific as possible. It helps if you include things like Operating System version (e.g., Snow Leopard 10.6.8) and anything that could help us in diagnosis.